# Can my application server find out which Java hosting provider it lives in?

Tags: heroku, hosting, cloud-foundry, application-server, cloudbees

I'd like to have my Scala application server find out if it's running inside Heroku or CloudBees or Cloud Foundry or something else. Is there some standard way of finding out which Java hosting provider is currently in use? (if any)

Perhaps the hosting provider's firewall/load-balancer/whatever adds some standard HTTP header that the app server could check? Or perhaps it's possible to do hosting provider specific checks somehow, for the most popular hosting providers?

---

Background: The app server could then show helpful tips to the server admin that tells him/her how to view the server's log files. This would be useful during the initial setup of the server + database, because then the admin needs to find a certain magic password in the log file, which s/he then uses to get access to the admin interface web pages the very first time (before any admin user exists in the database, see [this security question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35453/simple-and-secure-remote-installation-method-that-accepts-input-via-a-web-page)). — The installation would be more user-friendly, if the server could tell the admin exactly how to view the log files (which varies from hosting provider to hosting provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of cloudbees there are several ways, none of which are guaranteed to be future proof (given changing containers).

Perhaps what is needed is a standard environment variable to make this doable.

Comment: I guess that the situation is similar for other Java hosting providers, i.e. that there might be some provider specific way to identify the hosting provider, but no standard approach. — Concerning "there are several ways", would you perhaps like to briefly describe one or two of them?

Comment: I would look for the "app.port" system property which I think is exclusive to cloudbees containers at the moment. Otherwise looking for some telltale files in the app dir could work (Heroku coulid be identified possibly by a Procfile existing).